# C++: implement a graph

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a directed graph using a class in C++. I'm having trouble constructing the graph and adding edges. Here's a snippet from my code:

```
class Graph {
public:
   typedef unsigned node;

   Graph(size_t n)
    {
        vector<list<int>> graph(n, list<int>());
    }

    void make_edge(node node1, node node2)
    {
        size_t n;
        Graph graph(n);  // error here
        graph[node1].push_back(node2);
    }
...
...
...
}
```

EDIT:
I changed the parameters and its type. Now I get an error in the same place that says "Use of undeclared identifier 'graph'."

Comment: Well, there's no constructor that take an `int` and a `std::list<int>` indeed.

Comment: You have a constructor with *one* argument, but you're trying to call it with *two* arguments.

Comment: The _constructor_ is the function called `Graph`.  Look at the arguments that it takes, then look at the arguments being passed to it at "error here".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor has a local `vector` called "graph". Then `make_edge` creates a new `Graph` (with an indeterminate size) and calls it "graph", and you try to index this `Graph`.

I suspect that you intended the local variable in the constructor to be a member variable, and to use this in `make_edge`.

Like this:

```
class Graph {
public:
    typedef unsigned node;
    vector<list<int>> graph;

    Graph(size_t n) 
      : graph(n, list<int>())
    {
    }

    void make_edge(node node1, node node2)
    {
        graph[node1].push_back(node2);
    }
...
...
...
}
```

Comment: Note : the `list<int>()` temporary is unnecessary, `std::vector` default-constructs its contents.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a constructor taking a `size_t` as a parameter, but inside the `make_edge` method, you're trying to create a `Graph` variable using a constructor with the parameters `(int, list<int>())`.

You are missing the constructor accepting those two parameter types, you need to provide it.